# Why should not we setState in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

In this code sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/qxo15z8k0j

I tried to call the setState on componentDidMount on the child Component

Is that not a good practice to do ? why and if it is not where should we do the setstate and when can setState in componentDidMount

I see in this article, it is mentioned to fetchData in componentDidMount
https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Please suggest

Comment: `componentDidMount` is deprecated. Use `constructor` instead. It's not a good way to setState in `componentDidMount` because it will re-render your component. Instead you can manipulate vars inside `render` so it doesn't renders twice.

Comment: @Fawaz componentDidMount is not deprecated.

Comment: @AdrianLineweaver thanks for correcting, actually it was `componentWillMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is that not a good practice to do ?

Actually it's not.When we use setState inside componentDidMount,it will trigger an exact render() call and it happened before the component rendered so the user won't see the change.And it may sometimes lead to performance problem.

## when can setState in componentDidMount

This usually happened when you fetch data from network and should setState after get the data successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can setState inside componentDidMount.

Straight out of the docs:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen.

They do caution that this could cause a performance hit and suggest you can most likely set the initial state of the component in the constructor.